# How can I safely NFS mount /var/lib/kubelet in a kubernetes cluster with diskless worker nodes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, kubelet

**Background:**

I have a bare metal Kubernetes cluster. The master node is diskful, however all of the worker nodes are diskless, and PXE boot off of a machine which provides their OS image and non-volatile NFS mount points.

We found early on that we needed some kind of non-volatile storage so that the diskless nodes could store their configurations, kubernetes secrets, SSL keys, etc... Without the non-volatile storage, the nodes would have to be deleted and rejoined to the cluster every time they rebooted, which is obviously a pain.

So we created NFS mount partitions for /etc/kubernetes and /var/lib/kubelet so that the nodes could remember who they were and rejoin the cluster after a reboot.

**The Problem:**

However, we have run into a problem with kubeadm: It unmounts/remounts /var/lib/kubelet whenever you run kubeadm join. This leads to kubelet puking and dying because it can't find the appropriate device. The specific error is:

```
node6 kubelet: F0113 18:08:55.196706  210949 kubelet.go:1347] Failed to start ContainerManager failed to get rootfs info: failed to get device for dir "/var/lib/kubelet": could not find dev
ice with major: 0, minor: 46 in cached partitions map
```

If we unmount the NFS mount for /var/lib/kubelet before running kubeadm join, it works just fine, but gets us back to our original problem: the diskless node will not survive a reboot and automatically rejoin the cluster.

We tried to get around this by changing kubelet's k8s root, but it still leads to the same crash where kubelet gets confused about the device.

So my question is this:

**How can I properly set up an NFS mount point for /var/lib/kubelet, or otherwise configure kubelet, on my diskless worker nodes so that even when kubeadm mounts/unmounts that point I don't get a crash, and kubeadm's setup files are non-volatile?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue but fortunately this is fixed just couple of days back - https://github.com/google/cadvisor/pull/2787.

This hasn't been cut into a release yet. While this might make into 1.20.x, not really sure about previous versions. Might want to request for a backport on the issue at https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/98009 if required.